# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'pre.php' in /usr/share/tuleap/src/www/index.php

Tags: tuleap

I have installed xampp and then tuleap in centos and gave /usr/share/tuleap/src/www as document root in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

When I hit the url, I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(pre.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/tuleap/src/www/index.php on line 9

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'pre.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /usr/share/tuleap/src/www/index.php on line 9
```

I am also seeing that the document root points to /usr/share/tuleap/src/www and pre.php is not in this folder. Instead it is at include/pre.php I am totally confused on this directory structure. I didn't change any code after installing tuleap.

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I don't understand the link between xampp and Tuleap. Which type of installation did you do? Did you use the VirtualBox appliance, go for the full install or use docker? Tuleap needs to run on a fully dedicated RedHat/ CentOS 6 machine (virtual or otherwise) so there should be no playing about with your apache settings. At most, you should modify your hosts file.

Comment: Hi Jack, I am using centos 6 VPS from rootnerds. I have installed xampp and then tuleap as per the guidelines without missing anything from this site: http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html 
Next, I have added /usr/share/tuleap/src/www as the document root in /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf. From this moment I start getting the above error. Please visit: ashecache.com

I have been on it since a month now. This single small thing has become the show stopper. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, the guidelines don't mention xampp. In fact Tuleap comes with its own pre-configured apache settings so you don't need to set-up a virtual host.
Once you have finished the install and setup sections, run
`ifconfig` to find the machine's IP address.
Use this IP address and set an alias in your hosts files to connect to Tuleap from another machine.