# Tuleap Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'pre.php'

Tags: tuleap

I'm facing the same problem related in this question:

[Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'pre.php' in /usr/share/tuleap/src/www/index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046780/fatal-error-require-once-failed-opening-required-pre-php-in-usr-share-tul)

I'm trying to run Tuleap from source code using Wamp Server.
I have installed Wamp on Windows and extract the Tuleap files into www folder.
When I access the URL, I'm getting the following error:

( ! ) Warning: require_once(pre.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\tuleap-master\tuleap-master\src\www\index.php on line 9

( ! ) Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'pre.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\tuleap-master\tuleap-master\src\www\index.php on line 9

I found the file pre.php inside the folder "www/include/". I put this path in the file index.php and the problem was solved, but another problem related to path files was raised:

Warning: require_once(common/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\tuleap-master\tuleap-master\src\www\include\pre.php on line 1

I would like to know if there is some approach to solving this problem.

If is possible to run Tuleap in this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [this troubleshooting checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory). The problem seems to be that you need to set your include path.